# Can't create file with deleted file name at android 10

Tags: android, file, android-10.0, android-contentresolver

I want to keep a log text file for each day in the download folder. I want to store day based text files in my own Log folder(MyApp Log folder) in the Download folder.

When I delete the My App Log folder, I can't create this folder in the same location with the same name. Likewise, when the text file I created is deleted, I can't create a file with the same text file name. `resolver.insert(downloadUri, contentValues);` always returns null.

Even though I get a null result when I query whether there is a file belonging to that path, I can't create the same file.

**The function where I created the file:**

```
public static void createFile(){
    
        String contentType = "text/log";
        Date cDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").format(cDate);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, today + ".txt");//2021_10_13.txt
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, contentType);//text/log
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, seconds);//System.currentTimeMillis
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, seconds);//System.currentTimeMillis
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + "MyApp Log");//Download/MyApp Log
    
        ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    
        outputUri = resolver.insert(getDownloadUri(), contentValues);
    
        if (outputUri == null)
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");
    
        try (final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(outputUri)) {
            if (stream == null)
                return;

        } finally {
            ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
            updateValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);
            resolver.update(outputUri, updateValues, null, null);
        }
    }

    public static @NonNull
        Uri getDownloadUri() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
                return getLegacyUri(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            } else {
                return MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
        }
```

**The function I am querying if the file exists:**

```
    public static Uri getExternalContentUriFromFile(Uri externalUri, String filePath) {
        if (externalUri == null)
            return null;

        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(externalUri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID},
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=? ", new String[]{filePath}, null)) {

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                return Uri.withAppendedPath(externalUri, "" + id);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I cannot create a file with the same text file name.` Where are you trying to do so? Every time you call createFile()  the milli seconds are different.

Comment: `When I delete the My App Log folder` How are you doing that exactly?

Comment: `I can't create this folder in the same location with the same name.` How exactly are you trying to create a folder?

Comment: Dont call me at different posts for this post. If you need me here then call me at the post itself.

Comment: I created my own log folder in the download folder. (name of folder:MyApp Log). When I want to manually delete this folder from the device and create it again, I get the null uri error I mentioned above. There are times when I try seconds later, there are times when I try after a day.

Comment: What do you mean with manually? And you are not creating folders but inserting files. The side effect of inserting files is that folders mentioned in RELATIVE_PATH  can be created if they do not already exist.

Comment: You should react to all comments you get as they are not made to be neglected.

Comment: Yeap I know that RELATIVE_PATH side effect or using `Files.create()`. But my problem is not only creating folder but also creating text file with same name.

Comment: I still dont know hiw you delete manually.   And I repeat my first comment.

Comment: Answer to your first comment: 
The path of the log file I want to create: `/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyApp Log/2021_10_13.txt`
If I delete the entire `MyApp Log` folder, I cannot create this folder when I call this function again.
If I delete the `2021_13_10.txt` file in the MyApp Log folder, I cannot create a file with this name again.

Comment: Second question : I go to the download folder on the phone and delete the file, I delete by hand it myself, not programmatically.

Comment: `I go to the download folder on the phone` But how? Which app do you use for that? And how did you delete that file?

Comment: I enter the device Files application. I right click and delete file.

Comment: The Files app should not only delete the file from the storage but also delete the entry in the mediastore. If it does not delete the entry then trying to insert() the same display name with mediastore will not go. Use the mediastore to list the files in your own folder and see if it is still there.

Comment: On my Android 10 device Files app deletes the entry too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
        int fileNo = 0;
        Uri uri = saveToUri(fileName, contentType, seconds, relativePath);
        if (uri == null) {
            while (fileNo < 4 && uri == null) {
                fileNo++;
                fileName = AttachmentUtil.removeExtensionForName(fileName) + "(" + fileNo + ")" + extension;
                uri = saveToUri(fileName, contentType, seconds, storageName + File.separator + myDirName, storageUri);
            }
        }
```

**@Will V :**

```
 public static String removeExtensionForName(String fileName) {
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            return fileName.substring(0, i);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

And I got my code in above question into saveToUri function.

Comment: Hello friend, please, could you put the function code "saveToUri"

Comment: If possible post the code of the class "AttachmentUtil" Thank you very much